# How can I do two or more instructions in a loop in common-lisp?

Tags: loops, common-lisp, hashtable, nested-loops

I would like to know whats wrong with this code.Assume *corpus is a list of words ("at" "the" ...) and this code tries to keep them in a hash-table (word times-repeated-word)

```
(defparameter h (make-hash-table))
(defparameter ex 0)
(loop for x in *corpus
      do ((setf ex 0)
          (loop for y being the hash-keys of h
                if (equal x y) do ((incf (gethash y h)) (setf ex 1)))
                if (eql ex 0)
                do (setf (gethash x h) 1)))
```

If the word is in the hash-table just increase 1, else add a new pair.

Comment: Please format your code properly (using, e.g., Emacs). This is necessary for us to be able to read your code. E.g., you definitely have a spurious `(` after `do`, but I cannot figure out whether you ever close it (not that it is relevant). Also, you should paste the exact error message you see.

Comment: `gethash` takes a optional third argument _default_, which is returned if the key is not found in the hashtable. `incf` will happily increment this default value, and then update the hashtable with the new key. Thus, all you have to do in the outer loop is `(incf (gethash x h 0))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to iterate over a corpus of words; for each word *w*, if *w* is mapped to an integer *n* in some hash, you want to increment that number so that *w* is mapped to *n+1*; otherwise, you want to map that word to 1.

Basically, you want to do this:

```
(defun increment-corpus (corpus hash)
  (map nil
       (lambda (word)
         (incf (gethash word hash 0)))
       corpus))
```

- I am using [`MAP`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/f_map.htm) so that I can iterate over any sequence of words, not just lists.
- The result-type of `MAP` is `NIL`, because I don't care about the result, I just want to make side-effects.
- The function that is applied simply increments the current value bound to `word`. Note that [`GETHASH`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gethas.htm) provides a default form to be evaluated in case no value is bound to the given key. Here, I just need to put zero so that the increment works in all cases. I didn't read it at first, but [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357040/how-can-i-do-two-or-more-instructions-in-a-loop-in-common-lisp/39357949#comment66045335_39357040) from Terje D. already said it.

#### Example

```
(defparameter *hash* (make-hash-table :test #'equal))

(defun test (&rest words)
  (increment-corpus words *hash*)
  (maphash (lambda (&rest entry) (print entry)) *hash*))
```

The hash is initially empty.

```
> (test "a" "b" "c" "d")

("a" 1) 
("b" 1) 
("c" 1) 
("d" 1)

> (test "a")

("a" 2) 
("b" 1) 
("c" 1) 
("d" 1)

> (test "a" "b" "c" "x")

("a" 3) 
("b" 2) 
("c" 2) 
("d" 1) 
("x" 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

A block in CL looks like this:

```
(progn
  expression1
  expression2
  ...
  expressionn); the result of the form is result of expressionn
```

This can be used places where one expression is needed since a block is one expression. In loop `do` can be followed by one or more compound forms (function calls, macro calls, special forms, ...):

```
(loop :for element :in list
      :do expression1
          expression2
          expression3)
```

Comment: @RainerJoswig Fixed. Silly me. Had I at least been consistent :-p

Comment: Also: The `do` keyword can be followed by more than one form, so the `progn`is not neccessary.

Comment: @TerjeD. Thanks. I've learned something today too. I've always used `progn` and haven never actually though about it. The `loop` macro sure has its share of surprises.